# openui5 - How to connect to a mysql DB?

Tags: sapui5

I am learning OpenUI5, and would like to connect to a locally installed MYSQL Database, i understand that only Odata binding is supported for OpenUI5.

I do not see any connectors to connect to MYSQL(i do not know PHP either, so i cannot use the PHP connector).

All inputs and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
Chen

Comment: Sorry, but I fear you misunderstood some aspects about OpenUI5: It is a front-end only technology. The only communication it does is to a back-end server. It is the server who connects to the database, not OpenUI5. Also, JSON data is supported as well, not only Odata.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up something here. OpenUI5 is front-end only. The Database is in your back-end. What technology your back-end uses can be chosen by you (PHP, Java, Node, whatever you like).

You can communicate to your openUI5 App using an OData or plain JSON based service on your back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if MySQL allows JSONP calls. If so, you can use a JSONP call to the MySQL server on localhost to fetch the data. But this sounds like a hack.